# How to contribute a module from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, module

One Drupal module is already available and released in community(drupal.org) and developed by someone which is in Drupal 7 version.

Now I have upgraded this module to Drupal version 8.

So can you please help me with the steps to contribute this Drupal 8 module to community please?

Comment: What I mean, I have converted a contributed module from Drupal 7 (Which is developed by another user) to Drupal 8, and I wanted to share this to Drupal community?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the page explaining how to contribute in development:

https://www.drupal.org/contribute/development

You can register and ask additional question there too. But since you upgraded other's person module I guess you should contact module author.